# match search result two column with one input

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have two coulms in table one is name and lastname, and i have one input for search if i search full name with name and lastname then result is not available
[here is database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqzEX.png)

and input code is

```
<form class="form-inline" action="searchfrnd.php" method="GET">

            <input style="margin-top:20px;" type="search" class="form-control" name="frnd_search" placeholder="Search your Friends">

            </form>
```

and php code is

```
 $frnd_name=$_GET['frnd_search'];

$sql="select name,lastname,username,email from user where name='$frnd_name'   or lastname='$frnd_name'  or username='$frnd_name' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "".$row['name']." ".$row['lastname']."<br>"; }}
```

Comment: try add brackets to the sql, for example name='{$frnd_name}', let me know if the problem still persist.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT 
  name, lastname, username, email 
FROM 
  user 
WHERE 
  CONCAT('%',name,'%') LIKE '$frnd_name' OR
  CONCAT('%',lastname,'%') LIKE '$frnd_name' OR
  CONCAT('%',username,'%') LIKE '$frnd_name'
```

It will look for `name`, `lastname` and `username` in the form input. This is far from perfect, but does what you want it to do.

Please don't forget the security of your code, it is non-existent.

Answer (score 0):

```
$frnd_name = trim(preg_replace( "/[ ]+/", " ", $_GET['frnd_search'] ) );
$arr = explode(" ", $frnd_name, 2);
if(!empty($arr[1]))
    $sql_where = "name LIKE '%".$arr[0]."%' AND lastname LIKE '%".$arr[1]."%'";
else
    $sql_where = "name LIKE '%".$arr[0]."%' OR lastname LIKE '%".$arr[0]."%'";
$sql = "SELECT name,lastname,username,email FROM user WHERE ".$sql_where;
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "".$row['name']." ".$row['lastname']."<br>"; }}
```

Comment: yeah its working but there is problem that if i type "manoj kumar" and search then its show data which is match with "kumar " and " result show kartik kumar and then manoj kumar , I want to show result first which is searched

Comment: so you want when search string is "manoj kumar" the result should match with firstname/name=manoj (not kumar) AND lastname=kumar (not manoj). Is this right ?

Comment: but when i search only "kumar" then it should show all name with Firstname and "kumar"

Comment: First I need to make sure I fully understand you right: When the search string is "manoj kumar" it will show only users with (name/firstName="manoj" AND lastname="kumar"). When the search string is "kumar" it will show users with (name/firstName="kumar" OR lastname="kumar").

Comment: Based on this understanding: how the code should include username & email. I will update the code but to satisfy the desired result.

Comment: yeah its working but there is a one problem i have 2 user 1 is "kartik sen" and 2nd is "kartik kumar sen" ..when i search only "kartik sen " its show all result but whene i search "kartik kumar sen " its show only searched result   but I want that its should show "kartik kumar sen" and then after the result its should show  all result which is match with kartik also

Comment: I did not understand this from the main question. Anyway, this will lead us to rewrite this code & another similar after it.